# How to determine location of _main in x86-64 executable?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I am interested in constructing a CFG from an x86-64 executable using static methods. I am having trouble including the "main" function because there are no precomputed jumps to the main function; it appears the jump may not be computed until the program is actually run. As such, my CFG is missing one of the most important functions - the main one! How can I statically determine the location of _main?

Comment: From the file header. What format executable is it?

Comment: It's in ELF64 format.

Comment: It depends, but the entrypoint for a C program is commonly the CRT initialization function.  Which then calls main(), located by the linker.  Sounds like you need to generate a map file.

Comment: What might this file look like?

Answer (score 2):

For further information read [Microsoft PE specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg463119.aspx).

**Getting entry point address**

Base of actual PE executables (term `image` is preffered in documentation) lies in old DOS `.exe` MZ executables. First two bytes of every executable were ASCII 'M' and 'Z'.
Nowadays, DOS header is skipped. It used to contain values such as starting `CS`, `IP`, `SS` or `SP`.

1. Get value at offset `0x3C` in file. It is start of PE header.

PE header stores fields like target machine, number of sections and so on. These things are not important to you.

1. You can simply skip whole PE header. (Add `0x14` to your pointer - `sizeof(PE_HEADER_S)==20`)
2. After adding `20` bytes to your pointer, you're pointing to the start of PE optional header standard fields. On offset `0x10`, there's `DWORD` which contains address of entry point relative to image base.

**Getting file offset of entry point**

Getting file offset of entry point is bit more difficult. The process looks like this:

1. Find section containing entry point. Usually it is `.code` section, but it will be better if you compare starts of sections with base of code (value of base of code is located in PE optional header standard fields).
2. Substract virtual address of section (simply section start in memory when executable is loaded) => you will get offset of entry point (offset is relative from the start of section).
3. We have offset, so just add file offset of `.code` section to result of previous step, and you're done.

All this steps will not usually lead you to address of main, but to address of CRT entry point, which calls the `_main` function.

If you wan't to get address of main, you must go through PE object files and find symbol `_main` in symbol table.

Comment: Oh, I though he needs it for PE32+... Hmmm.